# Reading JSON object data and how to filter?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native

Currently I'm developing an application which uses Prepr.io as API for fetching my own videos which are also stored in Prepr.io. When I'm fetching data with this link: [https://cdn.prepr.io/publications?fields=items{file{cdn_files}}](https://cdn.prepr.io/publications?fields=items%7Bfile%7Bcdn_files%7D%7D) I get the following JSON as response:

```
Object {
  "after": "YWZ0ZXJfMjU=",
  "before": "YmVmb3JlXzA=",
  "items": Array [
    Object {
      "changed_on": "2022-02-28T12:16:31+00:00",
      "created_on": "2022-02-28T12:16:31+00:00",
      "id": "905f950f-3e18-4b40-8c72-f8d3e509e546",
      "items": Object {
        "en-US": Object {
          "beschikbaar_op_route": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "body": "Route Groningen stadspark",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2022-02-28T12:13:10+00:00",
                "id": "a3758c72-1074-4385-884e-34c4bd7d6e1d",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "route-groningen-stadspark",
              },
              Object {
                "body": "Route Leeuwarden Kalverdijkje",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2022-02-28T12:13:28+00:00",
                "id": "cc3cbe4b-536a-40e7-b69b-8bdddc24d445",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "route-leeuwarden-kalverdijkje",
              },
            ],
            "label": "Tag",
          },
          "file": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "author": null,
                "body": null,
                "cdn_files": Object {
                  "items": Array [
                    Object {
                      "bucket": null,
                      "cdn": "BunnyCdn",
                      "changed_on": null,
                      "created_on": "2021-05-11T13:02:22+00:00",
                      "extension": null,
                      "file": "c7f6339d-e686-41a1-82ef-e3fbb9ebb425.mp4",
                      "id": "51fbad9a-70a9-4f6e-abfb-59b7a3ab2857",
                      "label": "CdnFile",
                      "presets": Array [],
                      "profile": null,
                      "url": "https://5ge7hcv8ge1k.b-cdn.net/c7f6339d-e686-41a1-82ef-e3fbb9ebb425.mp4",
                    },
                  ],
                  "total": 1,
                },
                "changed_on": "2022-01-06T15:03:34+00:00",
                "created_on": "2021-05-11T13:02:07+00:00",
                "duration": 32640,
                "ended_on": null,
                "extension": "mp4",
                "height": 720,
                "id": "c7f6339d-e686-41a1-82ef-e3fbb9ebb425",
                "label": "Video",
                "mime_type": "video/mp4",
                "name": "Stang in de nek video",
                "original_name": "Stang in de nek",
                "reference_id": null,
                "replaceable": true,
                "started_on": null,
                "status": null,
                "width": 1280,
              },
            ],
            "label": "Asset",
          },
          "image": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "author": null,
                "body": null,
                "changed_on": "2021-03-16T08:41:28+00:00",
                "created_on": "2021-03-16T08:41:28+00:00",
                "extension": "jpg",
                "height": 1280,
                "id": "9cade08f-5d16-41d1-8007-d18a08f0cddd",
                "label": "Photo",
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
                "name": "b053b802-abf8-47b4-888a-9304712c0a41",
                "original_name": "b053b802-abf8-47b4-888a-9304712c0a41",
                "reference_id": null,
                "replaceable": true,
                "status": null,
                "width": 1920,
              },
            ],
            "label": "Asset",
          },
          "kenmerken": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "body": "Rollator",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T14:48:37+00:00",
                "id": "0af8af83-d353-4d05-aff2-b86be1bf12b8",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "rollator",
              },
            ],
            "label": "Tag",
          },
          "niveau": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "body": "Level 1",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2021-05-06T10:12:28+00:00",
                "id": "5d7cb8be-7bb2-4b96-9910-744303470e81",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "level-1",
              },
              Object {
                "body": "Level 2",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2021-05-06T10:12:30+00:00",
                "id": "eb867180-2343-4d44-a7a1-9cfecb127a69",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "level-2",
              },
            ],
            "label": "Tag",
          },
          "title": Object {
            "body": "bla",
            "changed_on": null,
            "created_on": "2022-02-28T12:16:31+00:00",
            "format": null,
            "id": "655331e9-5dcd-4fe9-8eeb-fed17d0a9155",
            "label": "Text",
          },
        },
      },
      "label": "Publication",
      "publish_on": Object {
        "en-US": "2022-02-28T12:16:00+00:00",
      },
      "read_time": Object {
        "en-US": 1,
      },
    },
    Object {
      "changed_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
      "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
      "id": "20a86707-6144-461f-9b2a-7ab27b834b79",
      "items": Object {
        "en-US": Object {
          "active": Object {
            "changed_on": null,
            "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
            "id": "d18f7a7e-785c-4a0f-b7ed-e60dc3a87f58",
            "label": "Boolean",
            "value": "1",
          },
          "audience": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "body": "Bewoner",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T14:42:56+00:00",
                "id": "d714c04b-5e6e-45ec-b082-dfa791b44fde",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "bewoner",
              },
            ],
            "label": "Tag",
          },
          "auto_increase": Object {
            "changed_on": null,
            "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
            "id": "c6c08428-91f0-463c-b63b-ad636104d58a",
            "label": "Boolean",
            "value": "1",
          },
          "auto_increase_level": Object {
            "changed_on": null,
            "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
            "id": "649fb6e6-ba05-47b5-a2d3-1224dce58c21",
            "label": "Integer",
            "value": 3,
          },
          "characteristics": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "body": "Man",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T14:48:37+00:00",
                "id": "5d6333be-2cee-49ce-a945-e292a4d88d1c",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "man",
              },
              Object {
                "body": "Vrouw",
                "changed_on": null,
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T14:48:37+00:00",
                "id": "4ecbc422-dd5f-48d6-aa09-2180627b6f0c",
                "label": "Tag",
                "slug": "vrouw",
              },
            ],
            "label": "Tag",
          },
          "program_comment": Object {
            "body": "probeersel",
            "changed_on": null,
            "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
            "format": null,
            "id": "9d5860cd-94f6-4b99-ad82-eeddec5792f4",
            "label": "Text",
          },
          "program_title": Object {
            "body": "Test programma 1",
            "changed_on": null,
            "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:57+00:00",
            "format": null,
            "id": "0f82e55c-609a-4e19-b68d-42d249d950bc",
            "label": "Text",
          },
          "routine": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "changed_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:02+00:00",
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:00:46+00:00",
                "id": "56e685fc-00c7-438b-93b7-ca1557dff671",
                "label": "Publication",
                "publish_on": Object {
                  "en-US": "2022-01-06T15:00:00+00:00",
                },
                "read_time": Object {
                  "en-US": 1,
                },
              },
              Object {
                "changed_on": "2022-01-06T15:00:33+00:00",
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:00:33+00:00",
                "id": "f54a9dc3-1133-4023-8c6e-634a321d22b6",
                "label": "Publication",
                "publish_on": Object {
                  "en-US": "2022-01-06T15:00:00+00:00",
                },
                "read_time": Object {
                  "en-US": 1,
                },
              },
            ],
            "label": "Publication",
          },
          "video": Object {
            "items": Array [
              Object {
                "changed_on": "2022-02-28T12:15:42+00:00",
                "created_on": "2022-01-06T14:59:30+00:00",
                "id": "a758aa90-3dc4-4382-ae59-fa43ca90eac3",
                "label": "Publication",
                "publish_on": Object {
                  "en-US": "2022-01-06T14:58:00+00:00",
                },
                "read_time": Object {
                  "en-US": 1,
                },
              },
            ],
            "label": "Publication",
          },
        },
      },
      "label": "Publication",
      "publish_on": Object {
        "en-US": "2022-01-06T15:01:00+00:00",
      },
      "read_time": Object {
        "en-US": 1,
      },
    },
    Object {
      "changed_on": "2022-01-06T15:01:02+00:00",
      "created_on": "2022-01-06T15:00:46+00:00",
      "id": "56e685fc-00c7-438b-93b7-ca1557dff671",
      "items": Object {
        "en-US": Object {
          "title": Object {
            "body": "Test routine 2",
            "changed_on": null,
```

I really want to filter the data so I can get for example only the videos with 'niveau' > 'level 1' But i don't know how i can get the data. In the response i get 'Object' but what does 'Object' means? Currently i'm developing the application in React Native Expo and the code which i use is:

```
const loadVideo = async() => {
        fetch('https://cdn.prepr.io/publications?fields=items{file{cdn_files}}', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer {Token}'}
        })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((r) => {
            console.log(r)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

Comment: use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in to iterate over the Object and save in some array.

Comment: @ShahanshahAlam Thank you, your solution was very simple but it works now!